# Ranking my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I have added a WordPress blog to my site, added non-canonical URLs, put it through Bing, and Google Webmaster tools added about 100 + backlinks, and I've not had one any of my Wordpress blog pages ran on SEO search engines at all, bing, yahoo, yahoo.co.jp, google.com and other google search pages including google.fr, all of which I want to be ranked for international traffic. The site is a little old, and I hope I am not recovering after old errors and penalities, because from what I have read it could take up to a year, so that's the reason I've been going the extra mile on it, and I have not added too many pages to it, and have recovered some configuration issues where a lot of pages were going to a bad 404 page... However, I have added WordPress to sites many times and can see a transparent issue, wondering if anyone has any tips to get the WordPress pages ranking up soon. Really never seent his issue before. So tried pretty much everything, the Yoast app says there is some conflict with having two sitemaps, but the problem is that the one for my main hosting from the hosting company, is actually important because it comprises the core sitemap for my HTML pages.... So Is there a way to utilize the 'Toggle' sitemaps function? Should matter though because I have even confirmed the site pages exist with an RSS feed in bing webmaster tools, but it won't even rank in bing when I type in site: followed by the domain dot com.... So this RSS feed is also catching data in webmaster tools however there is still nothing.

Any ideas? Anything would help, I lost a lot of ranking on an old blog I used for my business page, that I shut down as I decided to merge everything into one site and forward some of the links between each other, but now it is ranking much worse, and none of my new WordPress pages are ranking after 30 days. And, my apologies if the StackExchange system saw a duplicate memo, this was because the WordPress thread I followed on the site was actually related to WordPress drops... REALLY need help here, my WordPress ranking is fundamental to my site's traffic. Another concern of mine is that someone might be negative backlinking my old broken blog pages, so I keep adding redirects to supplement the negative SEO, it's really bizarre, but I am only happy to at least be ranking on my brand keywords again... Everything else though for external brand related keywords has been quite sabotaged.. And, to think it all use to come from WordPress, I was getting more than 100 clicks a day related to my blogs...

Comment: OK, do you know where this was? Because I only copied it from a message board that someone told me was not pertaining to 'Wordpress' and that was the comment.... I apologized for asking the question there, as it must have just been posted because it had threads realted to wordpress jobs, and the 'title' workplace, sounded very similar to the computer :) So, still don't think there's any answers and I tried deleting the other question... I will edit this up a little bit so it is at least not a duplicate...

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference now, I added two more paragraphs and edited the question anyway :) I really need answers, please bear with me! If you could take the duplication status off I  would appreciate it I need as much help as possible right now!

Comment: Again, this was the original message workplace.stackexchange.com... However I have edited the question paragraphs here a lot and added more text it is no longer duplicate, please take the duplication status off :)? I need as much attention as possible on the question at hand!

Comment: And yes in Workplace I had already gone and deleted that post so I would indeed appreciate it if you could revise calling this one out as a duplicate, seeing as though this is where the question should be :)